# Ruby regex matching with atomic expressions, not working

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm making this kind of matching:

```
"125co.txt".match /^(?>\d{1,11})(?!af|a|f)((?:(?:c?o|co?).*)?.*)$/i
```

The MatchData object is:

```
#<MatchData "125co.txt" 1:"co.txt">
```

I would like to have, as first item of that object, the matched number ("125") to perform some tasks.

It should be:

```
#<MatchData "125co.txt" 1:"125" 2:"co.txt">
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with additional parentheses for `(?>\d{1,11})`:

```
/^((?>\d{1,11}))(?!af|a|f)((?:(?:c?o|co?).*)?.*)$/i
```